# Inicializar QList<quint8> como parámetro de una función virtual

Tags: c++, qt

estoy declarando una función virtual, en la que le paso como parámetro una QList, y necesito inicializarla dentro de la propia declaración de la función.
Ayuda..!!! No recuerdo cómo se hacía... Lo he probado de la siguiente  manera pero el compilador me dice que no..

```
virtual bool ejecutar(QList<quint8> &Lista = NULL);
```

Se que hay algo muy mal, jaja, pero no logro corregirlo...

Gracias.

---

Hubo un error de n el código de arriba, el parámetro dentro de la función es el siguiente:

QList &Lista = Null

Comment: Referencias no pueden ser nulas.

Answer (score 0):

```
virtual bool ejecutar(QList<quint8> &Lista = NULL);
```

En C++, las referencias **no pueden ser nulas**. Una referencia debe apuntar siempre a un objeto válido, luego ese `= NULL` viola las reglas del lenguaje.

La función debería quedar así:

```
virtual bool ejecutar(QList<quint8> &Lista);
```

> y necesito inicializarla dentro de la propia declaración de la función

Dado que estás pasando `Lista`  como referencia, nada te impide modificar el estado de dicho objeto dentro de la función:

```
virtual bool ejecutar(QList<quint8> & Lista)
{
    Lista.clear();
    Lista << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4;
}
```